# Cauchy sequence for a continuous function

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

> Let $u_n\in\left(\mathcal{C(\Bbb{R},\Bbb{R}),\Vert\Vert_1}\right)$ with
>
> $$
> u_n = \left\{
>     \begin{array}{ll}
>         n-n^2\vert t\vert &\mbox{if}& n\vert t\vert\le 1 \\
>         0 && \mbox{otherwise}
>     \end{array}
> \right.
> $$
>
> Does $u_n$ is a Cauchy sequence?

$u_n$ is a Cauchy sequence if for every positive real number $\varepsilon>0$ there is a positive integer $N_{\varepsilon}$ such that for all positive integers $m,n>N_{\varepsilon}$, $\Vert(u_m-u_n)\Vert < \varepsilon$. I plot the graph of $u_n$ it's look like a triangle. Here $$\Vert u_m-u_n\Vert_1=\int_{0}^1\vert u_m(t)-u_n(t)\vert dt=\int_{0}^{1}\vert m-m^2t -n+n^2t\vert dt.$$

How can I continue?

Comment: why do you take $\int_{0}^1$? shouldn't it be from -1 to 1, or from -1/n to 1/n? Split the integral into two (or more, if necessary) integrals, by breaking the interval of integration into suitable smaller intervals, depending of where the sides of those triangles intersect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a Cauchy sequence, but first of all your last integrand and your limits of integration are not correct.  Observe that your $u_n$ are supported on $[-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}]$, not on $[0,1]$, and since your space is $C(\mathbb{R})$ you want to take integrals over the entire real line line.

In any case, the situation is not so bad.  Look at your functions geometrically.  They are iscosceles triangles centered at zero with height $n^2$ and base length $\frac{2}{n}$.  This gives a hint on how to bound the difference below.  Suppose $n>2m\geq K.$  Compute:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty|u_m-u_n|\,dt = \int_{-1/m}^{1/m}|u_m-u_n|\,dt =2  \int_{0}^{1/m}|u_m-u_n|\,dt$$

because our integrand is even, and now bound below (the first lower bound comes from the fact that the integrand is non-negative):

$$\int_{0}^{1/m}|u_m-u_n|\,dt\geq \int_{1/n}^{1/m}|u_m-u_n|\,dt=\int_{1/n}^{1/m}|u_m|\,dt$$ because $u_n=0$ for $t>1/n$.  But the vertical line $t=1/n$ meets the slanted line $y=m-m^2 t$ at $m-m^2/n$ so the integral is the area of a right triangle of height $m-m^2/n$ and base $1/m-1/n$ (the range of integration).

The integral is $$1/2(m-m^2/n)(1/m-1/n)\geq 1/2 \frac{m}{2}(\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{2m}) = 1/8.$$  Here we used $n>2m$.  This does not tend to zero as $K$ goes to infinity, so the sequence is not Cauchy.

Comment: Why can you suppose that $n>2m$? I don't understand the invterval of integration, did you forget $-1/n$ to $1/n$ ?Thanks